# the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt2}+\frac{3}{1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3}+\dots+\frac{n}{1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\dots+\sqrt n})$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I need to find:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} + \ldots + \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}}), n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Looking at denominators, I see that [(...) represents any element between] : $$ 1 \le (\ldots) \le 1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}$$

Then I take reverses and get:
$$ 1 \ge (\ldots) \ge \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}}$$

Then I put the other sequence on top of the former one (I see that the rightmost element is still the smallest one)
$$ 1 \ge (\ldots) \ge \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}}$$

Then I take the sum of n elements on every end of inequality (to sum up n times the biggest element and n times the smallest element) and get:
$$ n \ge (\ldots) \ge \frac{n^2}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}}$$

Ultimately I take into consideration $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and get:
$$ \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \ge (\ldots) \ge \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n}(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n})}$$

Now I can use the squeeze theorem and get:

- $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$
- $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n}(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n})} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n}}}{(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n})} \implies Stolz = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{(n)^2 }{\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

And that is pretty disappointing - I think that the solution is wrong. Does anybody see an error in my way of thinking?

Unfortunately, I can not use integrals while doing that exercise.

Comment: Can one use the Cesaro-Stolz theorem? I got $+\infty$ with it, not sure of my computation though...

Comment: I think I can, because the denominator $\implies \infty$. But I think that there is an error somewhere before, unfortunately.

Comment: Ohhh, you mean that you calculated the result using Stolz theorem at the beginning? And you got $\infty$???

Comment: yes I mean I used the Cesaro-Stolz theorem on it. I unsure of your computation above: at some point, you had $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n}}\leq 1$ and then your next line says: $\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n}}\leq 1$. it should instead say: $\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n}}\leq n$, shouldn't it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) indeed suffices, with a derivative-like limit (the last one below).

Let $a_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}$ and $b_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k/a_k$; we're computing
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{\sqrt{n}}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n-b_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{a_n}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1})
\\&=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{3/2}}{a_n}
\\&=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{3/2}-(n-1)^{3/2}}{a_n-a_{n-1}}
\\&=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{3/2}-(n-1)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{n}}
\\&=\color{gray}{2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-(1-1/n)^{3/2}}{1/n}}=\mathbf{3}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Give me a moment please, it got quite complicated for me

Comment: I don't understand move after Stolz theorem (from 1st line to 2nd). What happened to the denominator from 1st line? And what is those square roots? Ohhh, you used difference of squares, right?

Comment: And how did you get that $n^{3/2}$ in the 3rd line?

Comment: @theboyboy: 1) right; 2) $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}=\sqrt{n}(1+\ldots)$, and the "$(1+\ldots)$" tends to $2$.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I just never before used $n \implies \infty $ in the middle of my calculations. I thought that I need to change all the expression first and only then I am allowed to "work on n's".

Comment: Your solution looks good. I was curious if that could be done with squeeze theorem and calculations of adding another "parts of inequality" as I tried to calculate that?

Comment: @theboyboy: actually the logic is not to "use $n\to\infty$ in the middle"; we simply write the limit as a product of two limits, one of which is easy, and the other is what we continue calculating.

Comment: Oh, right, I think I get it. What about the squeeze theorem? I was doing that way similar but less complicated examples before. And here I was stuck.

Comment: @theboyboy: Well, I don't know. In fact I can't see any *straightforward* alternative. The ogirinal expression contains two summations, so the two applications of the Stolz–Cesàro theorem are necessary (if we don't want to use integrals or other tricks). Nowhere to turn.

Answer (score 1):

*If you are familiar with generalized harmonic numbers.*

The expression you are considering is
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum _{p=1}^n \frac{p}{H_p^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}$$ and, for large $p$, we have
$${H_p^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}=\frac{2 p^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24 \sqrt{p}}+O\left(\frac{1}{
   p^{5/2}}\right)$$
$$\frac{p}{H_p^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}=\frac {3}{2\sqrt{p}}-\frac {9}{8p\sqrt{p}}+\cdots$$
$$\sum _{p=1}^n \frac{p}{H_p^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}=3 \sqrt{n}+\left(\frac{3 \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}-\frac{9 \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{8}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\right)$$

$$a_n=3+\left(\frac{3 \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}-\frac{9 \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{8}\right)\frac 1 {\sqrt n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/2}
\approx \int_0^n x^{1/2} dx
=\dfrac{n^{3/2}}{3/2}
=\dfrac23 n^{3/2}
$
and
$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1/2}
\approx \int_0^n x^{-1/2} dx
=\dfrac{n^{1/2}}{1/2}
=2n^{1/2}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=1+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{3}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} + \ldots + \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{\sum_{j=1}^k j^{1/2}}\\
&\approx\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{\dfrac23 k^{3/2}}\\
&=\dfrac32\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1/2}\\
&\approx\dfrac32(2n^{1/2})\\
&=3n^{1/2}\\
\end{array}
$

so the limit is $3$.

Comment: As I said, I can use integrals, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not able to even tell if it's right or wrong :/